# how to retrieve date field regardless year in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve date from mysql database regardless year,
you thing we have 3 recrod

```
2015-4-4
2018-4-4
2009-4-5
```

I want to retrieve any date that has *-4-4 ,

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
select *
from Table1
where date_format(date ,'%m-%d') ='04-04'
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eacb/4)

Comment: May be I have written too technical words, but what I wanted to say was, using of equal to operator after formatting  by date_format looks ok. But using day() & month() functions sounds good. Not doubting on you skills friend, it is just my opinion, may it can be proved as wrong also!

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from your_table
where day(date_column) = 4
and month(date_column) = 4
```